# java calculator randomly outputted line

Tags: java

So I've just started java with a tiny bit of experience from a few other languages. I tried to make this basic calculator and had a lot of problems but managed to resolve most of them. The last thing that I can't seem to understand is a randomly triggered "This is an invalid input", every time my program runs once. "..." refers to irrelevant code. Everything else seems to work fine. Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calc {
...
        System.out.println("Would you like to use the calculator?(Y/N)");
        while(use){
            String usage=in.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            if(usage.equals("n")){use=false;}
        //input
            //operations
            else if(usage.equals("y")){
                ...(calculator code)
            System.out.println("Continue use? (Y/N)");
            }
            else {System.out.println("That is not a valid input");}
        }
    }
}
```

After running my code a few times, my output is

```
Would you like to use the calculator?(Y/N)
Y
Please input an operation: +,-,*,/,%, ^, or root
+
Calculator: Please input your first number.
1
Now enter your second number.
2
Calculating
3.0
Continue use? (Y/N)
That is not a valid input  <-- right there is the confusing part, why is that triggered?
Y
Please input an operation: +,-,*,/,%, ^, or root
```

Full code is on pastebin, if you somehow need it. http://pastebin.com/Qee2Hxe3

Comment: Instead of `System.out.println("That is not a valid input")`, do `System.out.println("That is not a valid input. usage = '" + usage + "'");` so you can see what the invalid input was. Maybe it was just a newline character, or some other whitespace.

Comment: Of all the solution's I actually prefer @kajacx 's comment to one of the answers below: "Alternativly: `double num1 = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());` Now you use only nextLine() to read input so problem solved. – kajacx"

Comment: Whether `parseDouble(nextLine())` or `nextDouble()`, I'd recommend catching the exception and retaking input rather than letting the program crap out if user doesn't enter a number

Comment: Another option would be to call `in.skip("\\n")` after `num2=in.nextDouble()`, which will consume the newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last input you read in your code when calculating is this:

```
  num2=in.nextDouble();
```

This reads the next characters and convert it to a double. However when you input your number, you also hit enter.
This means that after the `double`  is read, there is still a newline character left in the input buffer.

As the code goes back to the `String usage=in.nextLine().toLowerCase();`  , you will now read this newline.

You could just ignore empty input, by e.g. doing

```
 String usage=in.nextLine().toLowerCase().trim();
 if (usage.isEmpty()) {
      continue;
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

I checked the full code, and right before the loop first reiterates, there is a call to `in.nextDouble()`, this method reads a double but does not *consume* the line end, which makes the next `in.readLine()` return `\n` immidiately and the succeeding test fails.

A simple solution is to manually consume the line-end:

```
System.out.println(ans);
System.out.println("Continue use? (Y/N)");
in.nextLine();
```

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Edit made :)

Comment: Alternativly: `double num1 = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());` Now you use only `nextLine()` to read input so problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

I tested your code and found that a solution is to declare your scanner *inside* your while loop, like so:

```
while (use) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            String usage = in.nextLine().toLowerCase();
```

Here's what the problem is: first, you are entering your while loop, and usage is set equal to in.nextLine().  Since there is no next line, it waits for you to enter one.  You enter yes, after which you enter your formula.  Then it returns the answer, and goes back to the top of the while loop.  Once again, usage is set to equal in.nextLine, but there is already a next line (a blank one) and so usage is set to equal an empty String ("") which is neither "y" or "n".  Then it immediately goes to the "else" option at the end and prints the "invalid" message.
Re-assigning your scanner through each iteration of your while loop fixes this problem.